# Problem Accessing PXE server from a different vlan using Cisco switch

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

We are having a cisco layer 3 switch and a layer 2 switch. We don't have access to the cisco layer 3 switch(Its access is with higher authorities). I am having a PXE server configured which is connected to layer 3 switch. Layer 2 switch is cisco 2960 series switch is also connected from the layer 3 switch, and is configured for different vlan and also DHCP (with snooping enabled) configured.Snooping is enabled in layer2 switch, so that only the DHCP ips from this switch will be given. I am able to connect to PXE server from the PC which is connected to layer3 switch. But when I tried using it from PC connected to layer2 switch, I am not able to boot with PXE server.

Please tell me what are the things need to be done for accessing PXE server.

Comment: A diagram and ip/subnet info would be helpful.

Comment: Question about networks over which you have no control are explicitly off topic. Since the answer lies in the layer-3 switch over which you have no control, the question appears to be off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure IP helper on the router to make the PXE-boot packages transverse broadcast domains, aka. if your PXE server is in another subnet than your clients, you need to tell the router to forward broadcasts to the PXE server. It's quite similar to how you get a DHCP server to issue leases in a non-local subnet.